# specify changeset author for maven diff goal

Tags: liquibase

Is it possible to define changeset author when using maven liquibase "diff" goal?

Right now it uses your workstation's account under which you are logged in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nevermind - I looked into the plugin's source code and this is how I "fixed" it:

```
 <executions>
    <execution>                                   
       <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>diff</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
           <systemProperties>
               <user.name>someUserName</user.name>
           </systemProperties>
         </configuration>
     </execution>
 </executions>
```